# What's the best practice to close the Store instance in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am building a Flutter app with ObjectBox database.

App calls *openStore();* at launch, and saves the Store instance in a singleton class so that I can access to it from anywhere.

But I'm not sure when to call *store.close();*

In iOS we can execute code right before app termination using *applicationWillTerminate(_:)*

Unfortunately, Flutter does not provide us something like this.

I tried below code in the longest live expected StatefulWidget but it sometimes dispose sooner and the app loses access to the database.

```
@override
void dispose() {
  StoreHelper().store?.close();
  super.dispose();
}
```

My questions are...

1. What's the best practice to call *store.close()*?
2. What happen if I don't close the store? Would my app lose data persistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing seems OK to me. You could change it up slightly to `StoreHelper().close()` which would also clear set its Store reference to `null`, in which case if some other part of the app still tried to access, you could handle that (recognize it's closed or reopen it).

Also, in most cases, you should get away without closing the store explicitly. Unless you're doing (many) background write operations in which case you should probably try to at least wait for it to finish in `dispose()`.

Comment: "Also, in most cases, you should get away without closing the store explicitly" means that if my app has no background operation then I don't need to close the Store and let user terminate the app with the Store still open?

Comment: Yes, since you really can't prevent users from terminating the app whenever they want anyway :)

Comment: Thanks. BTW, the ObjectBox [getting started doc](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started) says "don't forget to close the store" in the comment in "Create a Store" section. So I thought I have to.

Comment: Good point, we should clarify that in the docs.